# Remove Continue reading -> from posts in aggregator site

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the FeedWordPress plugin to aggregate posts from other blogs. I am using the Magazine Basic theme.

Some posts form other blogs, often from the Twenty Eleven WP theme have a "Continue Reading ->" at the end of the excerpt that shows up in addition to the "Read more ->" built in for the Magazine Basic theme.

I want to remove the "Continue Reading ->" button from all excerpts on the landing page.

I noticed that "Continue Reading ->" shows up in the feed ([see here](http://datagamma.wordpress.com/feed/)) for blogs that end up having the "Continue Reading ->" button, while those that don't (e.g., [here](http://datafun.wordpress.com/feed/)) show "Continue Reading ->" just have a […] in the same place, which is fine.

I'm guessing I can remove the "Continue Reading ->" button using some sort of regex, but where is this done in the theme template? Perhaps in the index.php file?  I obviously can't edit the themes that the posts are being written in since I am aggregating.

Comment: Have you tried hiding the button using CSS?

Comment: No, I haven't. Any hints as to where to edit the CSS?

Comment: Post a link to your site on which these feeds are showing up and I'll give you the CSS you need to hide the buttons on the Landing Page. Then, you'll need to edit style.css in your theme to add the CSS.

Comment: Thanks! [Here is the site](https://notebooks.dataone.org/aggregator/). Notice how 3 of the 4 have the "Continue reading" link, whereas the other does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the theme's style.css. You should be able to edit it directly from the WordPress backend if you don't have access to the theme files from FTP.

```
.home article  p > a {display:none;} // to hide the continue reading link
.home article  p > a.more-link {display:inline;} // to display the read more button
```

This will work as long as there are no links inside the excerpts of text. Notice that I'm targeting the class of 'home' so that this will only affect the homepage.

If you are able to attach a class to the continue reading link, you could just target that class and avoid removing links from the excerpt, but it doesn't sound like you have access to those files.

Another way would be to use a little jQuery like so:

```
<script>$("a:contains('Continue Reading')").css("display", "none");</script>
```

This will ONLY target links with the words 'Continue Reading' in them so that might work better for you.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try it out, and get back to you soon.

Comment: Your solution will probably work, I just don't know what files in the Magazine Basic theme I would need to edit to fix this. (I really don't know php). Any hints? I'm thinking the jquery solution would be better as there could be other links that I don't want to remove

Comment: If you want to add the CSS, go to Appearance > Edit and edit style.css. Just to be safe, add it all the way at the bottom. If you want to implement the jQuery solution, repeat the above steps but edit footer.php. You can insert the script I provided anywhere but I would suggest placing it just before the </body> tag.

Answer (score 0):

> **Replace two this function in your function.php and generate your feed.**

```
function twentyeleven_continue_reading_link() {
    return ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . __( '[...]', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</a>';
}
endif;

function twentyeleven_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '' . twentyeleven_continue_reading_link();
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyeleven_auto_excerpt_more' );
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are editing functions in the Twenty Eleven theme, which I can not do. I am aggregating posts from other blogs, some of which have the Twenty Eleven theme. Really, ideally I just need to do some regex to replace the continue reading with nothing or something else at least

Answer (score 0):

I try many ways still not works too, but temporary you can use manual, update your css file when parse into html :

```
.link-more {
   display:none;
}
```